# How to implement a "params-like" method for internal usage using Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to implement something that works like `params`.

Normally in a RoR application you can use `params[:name]` to access the 'name' value. In my case I need to have "something" like `my_function_params[:name]` that works like `params[:name]`.

*I don't need all features of the `params` method because I will use that like a variable statement and only internally my methods*. This is because I would like to work on that instead of local variables.

Example:

```
# What I would like to do

my_function_params[:name] = "Test name"
if my_function_params[:name] == "Test name"
  ...
end
```

instead of

```
# What I would not do

name = "Test name" == "Test name"
if name
  ...
end
```

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Hash:

```
my_function_params = {name: "Test name"}
my_function_params[:attribute] = "Another attribute"

if my_function_params[:name] == "Test name"
  puts "hi"
end

=> hi
```